# google plus button's popover is not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus

I just wanted to ask you guys if someone knows why this is not working:

I am trying to plug google plus share button. button shows up fine. but if I go over with mouse, the popover shows up in the left top corner of the page and disappears again. If I click on g+ share button, nothing happens.

I just added what Google gave me as code snippet and did nothing else.

Comment: Do you have an example posted you can link to?

Comment: @abraham unfortunately my company has protected the beta version of what i am doing right now so i cannot give the link.. i also thought about how to provide a link. but couldnot find a way.. :(